# Is there a resource that moves diagonal?

Tags: resources, anylogic, warehouse

I am modeling an automated storage, retrieval system.
I need a reource that can move horizontally and vertically at the same time (diagonally) to store and retrieve agents in the Rack.
I found this model in AnyLogic cloud and I am interested to know, what kind of resource has been used?

[image: Image of Resource]

[Model in AnyLogic Cloud](https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/26975441-3ab7-4f53-b693-ece31e8f12ea?mode=SETTINGS)

I am using a Forklift now, but it can not move vertically and it needs more time to store and retrieve agents in the rack.

Comment: Are you sure you *need* this? Sounds like a classic case where abstraction does the job as well: Simply give your resources a higher speed that compensates for the extra distance they need to cover. In 95% of the cases, this will be good enough. Never try to model your system as realistic as possible. Always strive for "as simple to answer my question". Wdyt?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try higher speeds.
I should calculate the cycle time for storing and retrieving the boxes in the rack. Right now I am using a delay for vertical movement. 
The point is that I should validate my model with some analytic data from prevoius works. My model  overestimates the cycle time at the moment, which is not cool.
I wanted to make it as close as possible to the reality to increase the accuracy.